# Is it possible to insert PPT slides to revealjs Quarto presentation?

Tags: r, powerpoint, quarto

I am relatively new to Quarto, and I have made a revealjs Quarto presentation. A coworker prepared a couple of slides in PPT based on somewhat involved data merging, slicing and aggregating, something I am not willing to do again in R. I am required to insert those additional slides to the original Quarto document. Is it possible by any chance?

I checked Quarto guide https://quarto.org/docs/presentations/powerpoint.html, and it all is about creating PPT from scratch; this question appears to not have been asked before too.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A workaround could be that you could save each powerpoint slide that you want to include as an image, and then add that image as the background to a blank slide using `{background-image="path_to_image.png"}`?